PgPool failover error for primary when two nodes are down
I have a Postgres cluster working with PgPool. When two nodes, one primary and one replica, are down, PgPool will failover by running the script failover.sh specified in pgpool.conf for the replica, but never for the primary, plus PgPool freezes because failover is in process but there is no failover.
